# Android M + Retrofit + JSON : Can't make field constructor accessible

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am currently checking my app for M support. I get this error when I am making API calls with retrofit. This seems to be a json error that I getting. Has anybody else run into it yet? Here is my JSON helper class.

```
public class JsonHelper {

    private static final String JSON_PARSE_ERROR = "Unable to parse JSON: ";
    private static Gson sGson;
    private static Gson sExposeGson;

    static {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new EnumTypeAdapterFactory());
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(BlogCategoryDto.class, new BlogCategorySerializer());
        ...

        sGson = builder.create();

        builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
        sExposeGson = builder.create();
    }

    public static Gson getGson() {
        return sGson;
    }

    public static Gson getsExposeGsonGson() {
        return sExposeGson;
    }

    public static String toJson(@NonNull Object object) {
        return sGson.toJson(object);
    }

    public static String toJson(@NonNull Object object, @NonNull Type type) {
        return sGson.toJson(object, type);
    }

    public static String toExposeJson(@NonNull Object object) {
        return sExposeGson.toJson(object);
    }

    public static String toExposeJson(@NonNull Object object, @NonNull Type type) {
        return sExposeGson.toJson(object, type);
    }

    public static <T> T fromJson(@NonNull String content, @NonNull Class<T> clazz)
            throws IllegalStateException {
        try {
            return sGson.fromJson(content, clazz);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(JSON_PARSE_ERROR + content, e);
        }
    }

    public static <T> T fromJson(@NonNull String content, @NonNull Type type)
            throws IllegalStateException {
        try {
            return sGson.fromJson(content, type);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(JSON_PARSE_ERROR + content, e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error that is thrown

```
D/Retrofit﹕java.lang.SecurityException: Can't make field constructor accessible
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:334)
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.newDefaultConstructor(ConstructorConstructor.java:97)
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.get(ConstructorConstructor.java:79)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:359)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:52)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:359)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:122)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:46)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:92)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:91)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:142)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:359)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:122)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:46)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:92)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:91)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:142)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:359)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:52)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:359)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:122)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:46)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:92)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:91)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:142)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:359)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:809)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
        at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:63)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:367)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
        at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: There is an issue already opened at Gson project: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/648

Comment: Doesn't retrofit automatically include Gson?, why are you using a custom Json Factory?

Comment: @EfeKahraman your right seems there is an issue there

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments there is an issue allready opened at Gson project.

https://github.com/google/gson/issues/648

So it seems like a good idea to wait until they update their library. In the mean time I was able to make a quick fix by adding a line of code.

```
static {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

    ...

    builder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC);**
    builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
    sExposeGson = builder.create();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, now its not crashing at this point but its giving me all the null values in object where as the real JSON response had non null values in it. Any idea?

Comment: Because your model doesn't have `@Expose` annotation

Comment: Remove _builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();_ if not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

**This Worked for me.  Hope this could help someone.**

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC);
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way!

```
  GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC);
  Gson gson = builder.create();
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(URL)
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
      .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue using Retrofit2 in Android M as mentioned in [here](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/648)

one of the solution is to configure the GsonConverterFactory like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(URLWebService)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(
                           new GsonBuilder()
                           .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                           .create()
                        ))
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build();
```