# Working with GSON have error on android 6

Tags: android, json, gson

I wrote a code, get String base on Json format of a web service and then should to convert string to object. I wrote below code:

> ```
> //builder = new GsonBuilder();
> //builder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL,Modifier.TRANSIENT,Modifier.STATIC);
> //builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
> try {
>     Gson gson = new Gson();
>     //Gson gson = builder.create();
>     Type t = new TypeToken<ActionResult<Task>>() {}.getType();
>     String strJson = new String(jsonData).trim();
>     ActionResult<Task> result = gson.fromJson(strJson,t);
> ```

```
  }catch (Exception e) {
     Logger.e(e.getMessage());
 }
```

When i used `Gson gson = new Gson();` , i get an error and go to catch(my error is in below) but when i used `Gson gson = builder.create();`, the program have not any error but can't set data on result object.

Error:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Can't make field constructor accessible
```

The program have error in android 6 but have not any error on below 6.

Comment: could you add your build.gradle files (both)? I think you may need to downgrade gradle plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android M + Retrofit + JSON : Can't make field constructor accessible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431279/android-m-retrofit-json-cant-make-field-constructor-accessible)

Comment: @PauChorro this is not duplicate. I try the answer of above link but not work for me.

Comment: @piotrek1543 I wrote this code in eclipse not android studio and i used GSON2.2.4.jar version. which version should i used?